# Is it possible to restrict people access to peek through my files in a shared terminal Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare

I would like to have a shared terminal in VScode when working on a group project, but I don't want people peeking through my files on my computer. Is this possible to do right now with the LiveShare extension?

Answer (score 1):

You can share a terminal *read-only*, so only you as the host can run commands, but guest collaborators may just see the output of commands you run:

After starting a collaboration session, click `Share terminal... > Read-only`.
Alternatively, you can bring up the *Command Palette...*, (partially) enter `>Live Share: Share Terminal` and select `Read-only`.

Keep in mind that in *VS Code*, already opened terminals are automatically shared *read-only* by default when starting to *Share*. However, you can disable this in the *Settings*:

```json
"liveshare.autoShareTerminals": false
```

Note:

> If the collaboration session is in read-only mode, only read-only terminals can be shared by the host.

See also the *Visual Studio Live Share* Docs:

- [Sharing a terminal (Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/reference/security#sharing-a-terminal)
- [Share a terminal (How-to Guides: VS Code)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/use/vscode#share-a-terminal)

Comment: Cheers, would be nice if there was a read/write mode but only for the project folder